# why UniqueConstraint doesn't work in flask_sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I want an alternative of Django's `unique_together` in flask, seems `UniqueConstraint` is what I'm looking for, but doesn't work for me.

here is the example:

```
import os
from flask import Flask
from flask_script import Manager, Shell
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] =\
    'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'data.sqlite')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_COMMIT_ON_TEARDOWN'] = True
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

manager = Manager(app)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    __table_args__ = tuple(db.UniqueConstraint('name', 'address'))
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=False)
    address = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User (%s, %s)>' % (self.name, self.address)


def make_shell_context():
    return dict(app=app, db=db, user=User)
manager.add_command("shell", Shell(make_context=make_shell_context))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

Test it:

```
$ python test.py shell

In [1]: db.create_all()

In [2]: u1=user(name='a', address='x'); u2=user(name='a', address='x'); 
db.session.add(u1); db.session.add(u2); db.session.commit()

In [3]: user.query.all()
Out[3]: [<User (a, x)>, <User (a, x)>]
```

I also tried with:

```
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=False)
    address = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=False)
    db.UniqueConstraint('name', 'address')
```

not work either, what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

An instance of `UniqueConstraint` is iterable and in this case seems to stop iteration immediately, so

```
tuple(db.UniqueConstraint('name', 'address'))
```

results in an empty tuple, when you wanted a tuple that contains 1 item, the constraint instance. Use

```
__table_args__ = (db.UniqueConstraint('name', 'address'), )
```

or any other variation instead. As to why the latter form does not work, you [must apply table-level constraint objects using `__table_args__`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/constraints.html#setting-up-constraints-when-using-the-declarative-orm-extension) in declarative, if using *names*, or there will be no connection between the constraint construct and the `Table` backing the declarative model. If using `Column` objects the constraint can be created just about where ever, the connection is made through the `Column` object to the `Table`. There is also a third option: [`Table.append_constraint()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Table.append_constraint) method, which you can access through the model class' `__table__` attribute.

Comment: This does not work due to quotes around column names.

Comment: The quotes are not at fault, if you mean the Python's string delimiters; `UniqueConstraint` accepting column _names_ or `Column` objects is [documented](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/constraints.html#sqlalchemy.schema.UniqueConstraint.params.*columns). But: if your actual column is indeed a delimited identifier, which it will end up being, if you use mixed case or special characters, then indeed you must use the exact same case here. If my memory serves me right, SQLAlchemy will by default treat all lower case names as regular identifiers, i.e. the case insensitive kind.

Comment: The other thing to watch out for is using only names and _not actually passing_ `UniqueConstraint` in `__table_args__`, like in the other answer. In that case there is no connection between the `UniqueConstraint` and the `Table`. Using `Column` objects creates that connection, and so the `UniqueConstraint` can be created just about where ever.

Comment: And finally, a third thing to look for is not actually assinging a `tuple` as `__table_args__`, but instead just the `UniqueConstraint`, surrounded with parentheses. It is the _comma_ that makes the `tuple`.

Answer (score 8):

Passing variable names ( instead of strings ) worked for me.

```py
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=False)
    address = db.Column(db.String(64), nullable=False)
    db.UniqueConstraint(name, address)
```

Comment: I spent two hours until I realized I had quotes around my column names

Comment: his works not the __Table_args__ - I had a similar situation.

Comment: When passing names instead of `Column` objects the constraint construct must be passed in `__table_args__`, or there is no connection between the `Table` (backing your declarative class) and the constraint construct . The other option is to use [`Table.append_constraint`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Table.append_constraint), if using just names.

Comment: It is also important to make sure that `__table_args__` is actually a `tuple`, if trying to pass positional arguments. For example `(UniqueConstraint(...))` is not a tuple, it is just a constraint construct surrounded by parenthesis.