# Create MD5 of column in unique constraint sqlalchemy model

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

My model is as following and I want the unique index on a specific column with md5 hash but `func.md5(col2)` doesn't work.

```
class TestClass(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'my_table'
    id = db.Column(db.BigInteger, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    col1 = db.Column(db.String)
    col2 = db.Column(db.String)
    col3 = db.Column(db.Numeric)
    
    __table_args__ = (
        UniqueConstraint('col1', func.md5(col2), name='my_table_unique_idx')
    )
```

Comment: Be aware MD5 is broken, collision attack are known: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1434/are-there-two-known-strings-which-have-the-same-md5-hash-value, it is better to use SHA hashes.

Comment: You are passing the `UniqueConstraint` instance as `__table_args__`, with extra brackets, not a 1-tuple of the instance. Put another way, you are missing a comma. Funnily enough the constraint acts as an empty iterable in that situation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43977950/2681632

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions. ORM solution would look like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy import event
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base


username = 'postgres'
password = 'root'
servername = 'localhost'
databasename = 'database_name'
conn_string = f'postgresql+psycopg2://{username}:{password}@{servername}/{databasename}'

Base = declarative_base()


def add_hash(mapper, connection, table, *args, **kvargs):
    table.col1 = func.md5(table.col2)


class TestClass(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'my_table'

    id = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    col1 = Column(String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    col2 = Column(String)
    col3 = Column(Numeric)
    
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.col1 == other.col1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    engine = create_engine(conn_string)

    # create table if it doesn't exist
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

    # example when inserting record
    event.listen(TestClass, "before_insert", add_hash)
    with sessionmaker(engine)() as session:
        new_record = TestClass(col2='test row2', col3=1.2)
        session.add(new_record)
        session.commit()
```

The second solution would be creating trigger using SQL.

```
create or replace function fn_insert_md5() returns trigger as $$
begin
    if NEW.col1 is null then
        NEW.col1 := md5(NEW.col2);
    end if;
    return new;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;


create trigger trig_insert_md5
before insert
on my_table
for each row
execute procedure fn_insert_md5();
```

**EDIT:**
For adding constrain that will check if col2 hash value is same as col1 hash value

```
col2 = Column(String, CheckConstraint('col1=md5(col2)', name='my_table_unique_idx'))
```

Comment: Hey @pythonman, thanks for the answer but I don't want the hash value to be inserted in the table I just wanna have unique constraints on those columns.

Comment: Ok then it is enough to add parametars unique and nullable on col1. col1 = Column(String, unique=True, nullable=False) also you can add parameter index=True if you want that column to be indexed.

Comment: If you want to constrain that will check if col1 hash value = md5(col2), you can add CheckConstraint. It would look like this: col2 = Column(String, CheckConstraint('col1=md5(col2)'))